# A search box that searches for a specific tag composed of nested DIVs and shows the desire content and hides other data

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, search

New to this thing. Any idea how do i sort it in a specific data. For further explanation: If i search a name of a brand the out put will be show only the desire brand in A area.

```js
$("#search")..on("keyup", function() {
  var key = this.value;
  $(".tosearch").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggle($(this).text().indexOf(key) >= 0);
  });
});
```

```html
Search: <input id='search'></input>

<div class="tosearch">
  <div>
    <h2>A</h2>
    <div><a href="#top"> Back to the top</a></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/collections/agv"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/6434/files/agv-logo-120x120.jpg" />AGV</a>
    <div class="tosearch">AGV</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/collections/altamont"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/6434/files/altamont-logo-120x120.jpg" />ALTAMONT</a>
    <div class="tosearch">ALTAMONT</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/collections/arbor"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/6434/files/arbor-logo-120x120.jpg" />ARBOR</a>
    <div class="tosearch">ARBOR</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/collections/almost"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/6434/files/almost-logo2-120x120.jpg" />ALMOST</a>
    <div class="tosearch">ALMOST</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/collections/alpinestars"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/6434/files/alpinestars-logo-120x120.jpg" />ALPINESTARS</a>
    <div class="tosearch">ALPINESTARS</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/collections/answer-racing"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/6434/files/answer-racing-logo-120x120.jpg" />ANSWER RACING</a>
    <div class="tosearch">ANSWER RACING</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/collections/arai"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/6434/files/arai-logo-120x120.jpg" />ARAI</a>
    <div class="tosearch">ARAI</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly this is what you are looking for.

I removed the `.tosearch` class from the container div, otherwise it would also be filtered.

Currently it filters by the start of the word. A good idea is to use `toLowerCase()` so the filter is case insensitive. Currently it also hides the image by calling the `toggle()` on `parent()`.

```js
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
  var key = this.value;
  $(".tosearch").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().startsWith(key.toLowerCase()));
  });
});
```

```html
Search: <input id='search'></input>

<div>
  <div>
    <h2>A</h2>
    <div><a href="#top"> Back to the top</a></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/collections/agv"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/6434/files/agv-logo-120x120.jpg" />AGV</a>
    <div class="tosearch">AGV</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/collections/altamont"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/6434/files/altamont-logo-120x120.jpg" />ALTAMONT</a>
    <div class="tosearch">ALTAMONT</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/collections/arbor"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/6434/files/arbor-logo-120x120.jpg" />ARBOR</a>
    <div class="tosearch">ARBOR</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/collections/almost"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/6434/files/almost-logo2-120x120.jpg" />ALMOST</a>
    <div class="tosearch">ALMOST</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/collections/alpinestars"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/6434/files/alpinestars-logo-120x120.jpg" />ALPINESTARS</a>
    <div class="tosearch">ALPINESTARS</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/collections/answer-racing"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/6434/files/answer-racing-logo-120x120.jpg" />ANSWER RACING</a>
    <div class="tosearch">ANSWER RACING</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/collections/arai"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/6434/files/arai-logo-120x120.jpg" />ARAI</a>
    <div class="tosearch">ARAI</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sir i try your revise code and did not work nor the desire output shows. did i missed something on the code? attachment link: https://codepen.io/almighteus/pen/OxXWKP

Comment: You have to include jQuery for it to work. `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` If you want to use it on Codepen: click on Settings, JavaScript, Add External JavaScript and enter `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js`

Comment: Sir david  It did work  muchness for your help.I used the old one but i change it a little bit since i add more divs content/data's and i try your code but i dont know why it not working. It seems my weak points is constructing javascript functions. Sir can you help me construct a new javascript one if i add a anchor link. search js: https://codepen.io/almighteus/pen/OxXWKP and for anchor js: https://codepen.io/almighteus/pen/NarpVw

Comment: No problem. I created a new codepen for you: [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGzWVq)

Comment: Muchness for the help Sir David. the new javascript you made is exact on what i desire.